# Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, attributes

I imported my project from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio`. As it is merging all the files, I am getting error : `Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.`
Check my below libraries :

```
compile project(':staggeredGrid')
compile project(':mobikwikSDK')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

I am new to `Android Studio` so I don't have any idea about how can I solved this. I tried to change that attribute name but there are many same names so I am unable to go ahead.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock is deprecated so migrate to [AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Remove

```
 compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

Add

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
```

Comment: Works, Thanks mate!

Comment: it doesn't support com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1 as  i am using min sdk 19

Comment: @sJy I encountred the same problem adding "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'"  it is underlined with a message "the support library should not use a different 24 than  the compileSdkVerion (19)

Comment: @Rodrigo Is it your compileSdkVersion which is causing the problem?? Because v24 requires compileSdkVersion to be not less than 24. It shouldn't be min sdk. Correct??

Comment: @sJy thank you for answering, my compileSdkVersion is 19, what should i do to resolve the problem above

Comment: @Rodrigo Update compileSdkVersion to 24 if you need to use v24.x.x

Comment: @sJy I have  updated and still the same problem. always underlined  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0

Comment: @Rodrigo Dont know exactly your issue. Suggest to clearing the cache & restarting Android Studio, Clean & Rebuild. Check SDK manager too to verify that SDK 24 is installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149612/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-sjy).

Comment: @sJy I am in I've let u a message